# Laravel отложенная очередь не работает

Tags: php, laravel, очередь

Есть некий контролер который получает массив данных. Его нужно обработать в очереди с задержкой между задачами.

Выполняю:

```
foreach ($trades as $key => $trade){
    $data = [...];   
    $delay = ($key + 1) * 2; // например
    $job = (new ProcessTrade($data))->delay($delay);
    $this->dispatch($job);
}
```

Очередь выполняется сразу. При этом:

> QUEUE_DRIVER=database

Клас очереди использует Queueable

```
class ProcessTrade implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    ...
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А саму очередь запускали через php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
перед (или после) создания задач? Драйвер для очереди это всего лишь место для хранения задач и их параметров, плюс доп. значения. (https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues) Нужно запускать и процесс, который будет непосредственно брать задачи из места хранения, и выполнять их.

Comment: Висит через supervisor процесс на выполнение очереди. Написал же - очередь выполняется, игнорируется лишь задержка.

Comment: Ключ ($key) случаем не ноль? Если не получается так то попробуйте ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds($delay))

Comment: К сожалению delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds($delay)) так же не помогает
По логам supervisor все задачи выполняются без задержки одна за другой

Comment: В Интернете читал что только для первой задачи можно выставить интервал, остальные выполняются без задержки. нужно читать код, в доках такого нет.